# Two methods on same name in Javascript possible to execute each?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to execute two same name function in Javascript?

Actually its a predefined other library function. So, I can't change name of functions. Both are coded in next to each other.

For example:

```js
var a = function() {alert(1)}
var a = function() {alert(2)}
a();
```

This function will be called by some dynamic user. Is there any way to trigger both alerts with a single call? like `this.super()`.

Comment: You don't really have two methods, the latter variable with the same name overwrites the first one, as you can't have two variables with the same name. So, in short, no, you can't do that.

Comment: Why do you need this? I can think of no language where anything like this would be possible. Why not just have a single function which calls a variable set dynamically based on the state of the user?

Comment: i just need to do like that... just a curious to know. i think definitely there is a way to do this. thats y i asked here :( .. i know it... second one will overwrite first.. but still trying to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You could capture a and hold it by another name before you load the second function...

```js
var a = function() {alert(1)}
var a_proxy = a;
var a = function() {alert(2)}
a();
a_proxy();
```

Comment: if it is called by me then, i can call like u told. but its called by server

Comment: If nothing else is possible then you could try to proxy the second function named "a" and then reload the first javascript file manually to get the original function "a" back in scope.

Comment: both are loaded in same file :(

Comment: one will be given by user... user may give or maynot

Comment: another one is predefined one

Comment: Something does not sound right - there is no way to have two functions of the same name in one file and not have the second overwrite the first as adeneo said.

Answer (score 1):

is it not possible for you to put both of the functions into one main function and then set 'a' as that new function.

```js
var a = function() {alert(1); alert(2);}

a();
```